# Original Price And Special Price Issue in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, price, special-price

I want like this If original price is higher than the special price than original price should be hide in product details and throw out the check out page.

Can you please let me know where to add this calculation in magento files? If you can show me the location of the file than i can add some code over there.

Thanks In advance.

Comment: Please describe your question briefly, what is your goal, and what you have done.

Comment: Magneto 2 show only original price when special price is higher than original price but we need to show only special price when special price higher.